# chrome.tabs.create in popup.html is opening infinite number of tabs. How to open one tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This opens infinite number of tabs with popup.html, quite obviously. How do I change it so that only one tab is opened.

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {
        // Tab opened.

    });
```

Edit: (A basic popup.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">


    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title> Chrome Extension</title>
          <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />-->
      </head>
      <body id="container">
        <div id="left">
          <div class="input-wrapper">

        hello

          </div>


    </div> <!-- end #left -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

popup.js

```
function openTab()
{
    filename = "popup.html"

  var myid = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id");
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(
  function(win)
  {
    chrome.tabs.query({'windowId': win.id},
    function(tabArray)
    {
      for(var i in tabArray)
      {
        if(tabArray[i].url == "chrome-extension://" + myid + "/" + filename)
        {
          // console.log("already opened");
          chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[i].id, {active: true});
          return;
        }
      }
      chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL(filename)});
    });
  });
}

openTab();
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
    "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "App",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],
   "permissions": [ "<all_urls>", 
                  "storage",
                  "tabs",
               "contextMenus" ]


}
```

Comment: Why not to define a variable in background page which should store tab id of the popup, if it's already open? Otherwise you should enumerate existing tabs with `query` and create a new one only if required tab is not found.

Comment: If you handle popup manually, you should remove `popup.html` from manifest. Also you open the same page from itself ;-).

Comment: Yes, I sort of understood the problem. What should be there in the manifest.json then as removing popup.html doesn't make it work either.

Comment: After you remove popup reference from the manifest, add to you background page something like `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){openTab();})`. Also don't forget to move popup.js reference from popup.html to the background page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of searhing for specific tab. If the tab is not present, then the function will open it, otherwise the existing tab will be made active.

```
function openTab(filename)
{
  var myid = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id");
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(
  function(win)
  {
    chrome.tabs.query({'windowId': win.id},
    function(tabArray)
    {
      for(var i in tabArray)
      {
        if(tabArray[i].url == "chrome-extension://" + myid + "/" + filename)
        {
          // console.log("already opened");
          chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[i].id, {active: true});
          return;
        }
      }
      chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL(filename)});
    });
  });
}
```

Alternatively you can store new tab id during its creation in background page (something like a draft below) and clean up the variable when the tab is closed (by means of `chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener`).

```
if(chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().savedTabId != undefined)
{
  chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL(filename)},
  function(tab){
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().savedTabId = tab.id;
  });
}
```

Comment: Had tried your first method before. Weirdly, and even now, it just opens the popup at the extension itself and not in a new tab.

Comment: if(tabArray[i].url == "chrome-extension://" + myid + "/" filename) I get a weird Uncaught identifier error in that line. Any idea why?

Comment: @Puck, It was a typo there - missed `+` - fixed 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Ah, yes. A tiny bit of an issue. What happens here is this: When I click on the button, it first opens up a popup near the extension, and then shuts it, and opens a new tab. Have similar delay in yours?

Comment: @Puck, I don't have neither delay nor excessive popups. I think you should show more code, including manifest and how you call the stuff.